# How do you modify Heroku's nodejs buildpack to install Docker?

Tags: node.js, shell, heroku, docker

I am deploying a node application to Heroku that needs to run a script via docker, for example:

```
exec('docker run --volume=$(pwd):/etc...')
```

However, Heroku does not come with Docker installed and I am unsure how to modify Heroku's [node buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) to make Docker available.

I've tried using the https://get.docker.com/ script to download and install Docker, for example:

```
install_docker() {
  echo "Downloading and installing docker..."
  local code=$(curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh)
  if [ "$code" != "200" ]; then
    echo "Unable to download docker does it exist?" && false
  fi
}
```

However, this just results in the following error:

> "su: must be run from a terminal"

Any ideas? Thank you for your time.